# Jinja2 scope issues with blocks and includes

Tags: variables, scope, jinja2

Here's a simple template structure that consists of three files:

`wrapper.html`, which defines the basic structure of a page.  It has some blocks that can be extended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/something.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">

        <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block header %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

`main.html` is the the file that I give to jinja2 to format.

```
{% extends "wrapper.html" %}
{% set title = title | default("Untitled") %}

{% block header %}
    <h1>Welcome to {{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include "included.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

and `included.html` has some extra stuff I don't want to put into `main.html` for whatever reason

```
<p>In this page ({{ title }}), we will discuss all kinds of things.</p>
<p>Blah blah blah...</p>
```

My problem is that when missing a title, everything gets filled with "Untitled" except for one place: the `included.html` file.
I have found two ways of fixing this.

1. Add `{% set title = title %}` inside the `{% block body %}` of `main.html` (What?  Why does that even work?)
2. Move the `{% set title = title | default("Untitled") %}` to `wrapper.html`

I like neither of these options.  The first one for obvious reasons, and the second one because if I might want to extend `wrapper.html` in a number of ways and "Untitled" may not always be the best choice for an untitled page.

So my question is this: Is there any way I can I get `included.html` to recognize variables from `main.html` that are not directly defined in the block scope?
I would also like to know if I'm using Jinja2 incorrectly.